# How to handle errors related to sys.argv[] in python ?

Tags: python, argparse

I have write down a simple code to open a csv file that  reads data frame. The code is able to print  data frame. To make this code more interactive i have integrated a functionality so that it can raise an error if sys.argv[1] is not true. Unfortunately, i am not able to properly integrate the "raise exception part", after struggling too much  I'm looking for a solution. The code is given bellow (Though, i have tried so many thing with the native code but here i am pasting only the last change that i have made to achieve my goal (i.e raise exception if sys.argv[1] is not True ): Thanks

```
class My_csv_class(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.csv_path = sys.argv[1]

    def csv_open(self):

        try:
            self.r = pd.read_csv(self.csv_path)
        except IndexError:
            print "Cannot open the file: "
        else:
            return self.r 

    def print_r(self):

        self.r


if __name__=="__main__":

    a = My_csv_class()
    a.csv_open()
    a.print_r()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argparse` is built to make your command line parsing easier.

```
class My_csv_class(object):

    def __init__(self, csv_path):
        self.csv_path = csv_path

    def csv_open(self):
        try:
            self.r = pd.read_csv(self.csv_path)
        except IndexError:
            print "Cannot open the file: "
        else:
            return self.r 


if __name__=="__main__":
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-f", "--filepath",
                        required=True,
                        default=None,
                        help="Path to target CSV file")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    a = My_csv_class(args.filepath)
    a.csv_open()
    a.print_r()
```

With `required=True`, if the option is not given, an error will be automatically raised by the parser.

Comment: Your suggestion is exceptionally good for my code, Though, my Qsn. was not answered with this but after running this i find it more usable. thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem!  I find that `argparse` takes care of the majority of my command line argument parsing needs.

Answer (score 4):

The exception is raised in your `__init__` method. You could put the `try..except` around the instance creation:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    try:
        a = My_csv_class()
    except IndexError:
        print "You did not specify a file"
        sys.exit(1)
    a.csv_open()
    a.print_r()
```

However, it is more common to handle command line issues *outside* of such code. Keep your code re-usable without a command line and put all your 'script tasks' in the `__main__` guarded code:

```
class My_csv_class(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.csv_path = filename

    def csv_open(self):
        self.r = pd.read_csv(self.csv_path)

    def print_r(self):
        self.r

if __name__=="__main__":
    try:
        filename = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        print "You did not specify a file"
        sys.exit(1)

    a = My_csv_class(filename)
    a.csv_open()
    a.print_r()
```

Comment: I never think about it before but i really appreciate your idea about the re-usability of code. With your comment i have earned and learned  a very important concept.thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following

```
if os.path.isfile(sys.argv[1]): #if this is  a file 
   #do your work
```

in your code:

```
import os
import sys


class My_csv_class(object):

     def __init__(self):

         self.csv_path = sys.argv[1]

     def csv_open(self):

         if os.path.isfile(self.csv_path):
            self.r = pd.read_csv(self.csv_path)
         else:
            return self.r 

     def print_r(self):

         self.r


if __name__=="__main__":

   a = My_csv_class()
   a.csv_open()
   a.print_r()
```